# Преобразовать матрицу в список кортежей Python

Tags: python, матрицы, tuple

Дана матрица N*N, состоящая из 0 и 1. Необходимо преобразовать её в список кортежей длины N. Количество элементов в списке равно количеству единиц в матрице.

> Например, [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]] -> [(0, 0, 3)]

Как можно это реализовать на Python?

Comment: А каким образом получилось "3" в желаемом ответе?

Comment: Т.к. N = 3. (то есть, матрица 3x3). На месте единицы указывается размер (N).

Comment: А что бы было в случае [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]] и в случае [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] ?

Comment: [(3, 0, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 0, 3)]; [(3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)] (9 штук по (3, 3, 3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После дискуссии в комментариях меня гложут смутные сомнения что вы правильно сформулировали задания. Что-то из задания вы либо неправильно поняли, либо неверно формулируете. Тем не менее привожу решение задачи *именно в вашей формулировке*.

```
N=len(arr)
rezz=[]
for el in arr:
    s=el.count(1)
    rez=[0,0,0]
    for i,ell in enumerate(el):
        if ell==1:
            rez[i]=N
    for _ in range(s):
        rezz.append(tuple(rez))
```

и ее результаты для ваших контрольных случаев:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
[(0, 0, 3)]


[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
[(3, 0, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 0, 3)]

[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[(3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
```

и еще один дополнительный

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[(3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 0, 3), (3, 0, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: Спасибо) Всё работает